# How to pass extra parameters in HTTP DELETE request?

Tags: rest, http, web

I am writing a REST API, which supports POST/GET/DELETE method for the same url.

For the DELETE method, the API needs extra parameters (details of the deletion). But the library I am using doesn't support request body for DELETE method, how can I do it?

If I put the parameter in URL like:

```
DELETE /API/Resource/id/parameter
```

Then I break the RESTyness. 
Or I need to use another method POST/PUT, which is not RESTy, either.

Comment: Use query parameters or introduce custom request header(s) or change  the library you are using ;)  You should be more specific on what is a purpose of the extra parameters.

Comment: A URI itself does not state whether it (or the endpoint/resource behind) adheres to REST constraints or not. After all, a URI remains a URI no matter what and is neither RESTful nor RESTless. Also, the HTTP operation used does not really give a clue on whether the interaction is RESTful or RESTless. REST occurs from the interaction client and server have and when a client is only using the information provided by the server (think of Web surfing for applications)

Answer (score -2):

Why is POST / PUT not RESTy? Take a look at the [twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/destroy/%3Aid): You can destroy a status by POSTing to `/statuses/id/destroy`. That request does accept parameters. You could do something similar to this:

```
POST /API/Resource/id/destroy
```

I think that is RESTy enough.

Comment: Destroy is an action, not a resource... Looks we have to live with the loose definition of REST.

Comment: @hfhc2, IMHO twitter API is the worse API I've ever used. Using it as an example is not a good idea.